# line height issue affecting div height

Tags: css

on this [page](http://provisions.convoy.nyc/) i'm having an issue where the line height is slightly affecting the height of the div, so when you scroll there's a few pixel high gap that is basically padding the bottom of the homepage hero. see below image 
[image: see the white line below "shopping" cutting off the top of the black text?]

i've isolated the issue to deal with the line height, and if i set it to 0 on the entire page it fixes the issue, but then the text becomes unreadable because it is smushed. how do i get rid of the line height issue just for this but preserve my text as it is (1.67)?

here's the CSS

```
#content {
    line-height: 0 !important;
}

* {
    line-height: 1.67;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.67;
}
```

Comment: Link is bad. Supply your mark up here.

Comment: The padding on the hero is gone in Firefox. Did you fix it?

Comment: @Rob, it's a dead link on Chrome (for some reason). But it works in FF. And you're right, code should be provided in question.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome... The link isn't dead.

Comment: @Rob sorry about that it's working fine for me. what is the issue?

Comment: @Michael_B i looked at background check but ended up using this. only requirement is the header has to be fixed. http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting margin-bottom to -10px on #home_wrapper seems to fix the issue.